# Why am I getting the Stack Overflow error?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I get a Stack Overflow error but I don't seem to know what's wrong. This is Database class helps me to get FirebaseDatabase information.

```
 import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    import 'User.dart';
    import 'dart:async';


    class FireDatabase{
      FireDatabase();

      DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
      DatabaseReference transactionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("transactions");
      User user = new User();


     getDatabaseUser(String cUid){
        userRef.orderByChild(cUid).once().then((DataSnapshot data){
          if (data.value!=null) {
            return data.value;
          } else {
            print("prints - database.dart : data.value of user is empty/null");
            return null;
          }
        },onError: (e){
          print("prints - database.dart " + e.toString());
          return null;
        });
        return null;
      }

      getDatabaseTransactions(String cUid) {
        transactionsRef.orderByChild("transactions").once().then((DataSnapshot data){
          if(data.value!=null) {
            return data.value;
          } else {
            print("prints - database.dart : data.value of user is empty/null");
            return null;
          }
        },onError: (e){
          print("prints - database.dart " + e.toString());
          return null;
        });
        return null;
      }

      getDatabaseTransaction(String cUid) {
        transactionsRef.orderByChild(cUid).limitToFirst(1).once().then((DataSnapshot data){
          if(data.value!=null) {
            return data.value;
          } else {
            print("prints - database.dart : data.value of user is empty/null");
            return null;
          }
        },onError: (e){
          print("prints - database.dart " + e.toString());
          return null;
        });
        return null;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Does the exception output provide any information about what causes the exception? I didn't spot anything that could cause endless recursion in your code. Perhaps your `User` class has a getter that returns itself instead of the backing field (missing `_`)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this syntax, but to me the `FireDatabase();` call implies calling a constrcutor of this class or somehting, as the first thing of this class? (not posted as an answer, as for all I know this is something way normal in this case)

Comment: @Nanne Yes that is a constructor.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Can importing User class inside the Database class and importing Database class inside the User class be a problem maybe?

Comment: That's not about imports. Dart can cope with circular imports just fine. It's about code execution where code executes itself forever in circles until it runs out of stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the problem was that I had 2 classes, now within both classes, I instantiated each other class in a recursive manner.

Here is an example:

```dart
class Firestore{
  final auth = Auth();
}


class Auth{
  final fireStore = Firestore();
}
```

As you can see each class is calling the other class, that what caused the `StackOverflow`.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a `User` class in the Database class

```
User user = new User();
```

seem to have been the problem but luckily I was not using it anyway, the User gets stored in the User class

Answer (score 0):

for me in my class of FireBaseServices
i was creating an instance of itself which was causing the error.

```
 class FireBaseServices {
   FireBaseServices _fireBaseServices_instance = FireBaseServices();
```

stackOverflow was occuring due to some sort of Recursion happening.

I fixed it by removing the instance creation line.

Yeppeeeee.... it worked well.  Thanks Flutter Community.